# How do you save a S4 class object in python using Rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, r-s4

I have a python S4 object that i want to store for future use in python using rpy2. I then wish to import this from a file back into R when required. 
How would I go about doing this?

Python 2.7 
R 3.1.2

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: Specifically add some code to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: If S4 is referred to the objects in R, your best bet would be to save objects in .RData files (`save(..., file = ".RData")`.).

Answer (score 0):

In python you can start with observing the slot names of your R object as follows:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri as rpynp

tuple(object.slotnames())
```

This gives the parameter names of your object. You could then see the parameter values:

```
x = object.slots['slotname']
```

I assume you can figure out how to save your data into a file and how to import it in R.

I hope this answers your question. I agree with @Ram that your question is not so clear. Good luck.